# How to update state of class component from functional component using useContext

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am receiving an invalid hook call error when I try to update the state of my main app class component from my home page functional component. I am trying to send a string to update the state of menuId from home.jsx using useContext. everytime I press a button to update the string it returns the invalid hook error

App.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import Home from './pages/home';
import NavBar from './components/nav-bar';
import parseRoute from './lib/parse-route';
import AppContext from './lib/app-context';
import MenuPage from './components/menu-page';
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      route: parseRoute(window.location.hash),
      menuId: ''
    };
    this.updateMenu = this.updateMenu.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    addEventListener('hashchange', event => {
      this.setState({ route: parseRoute(window.location.hash) });
    });
  }

  renderPage() {
    const { route } = this.state;
    if (route.path === '') {
      return <Home />;
    }
    if (route.path === 'menu') {
      return <MenuPage />;
    }
  }

  updateMenu(id) {
    this.setState({ route: 'menu', menuId: id });
  }

  render() {
    const { route, menuId } = this.state;
    const updateMenuId = this.updateMenu;
    const contextValue = {
      route,
      menuId,
      updateMenuId
    };
    return (
      <AppContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
        <div>
          <NavBar />
          {this.renderPage()}
        </div>
      </AppContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

home.jsx

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState, useContext } from 'react';
import AppContext from '../lib/app-context';
import parseRoute from '../lib/parse-route';
const apiKey = '';
const mapApiJs = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js';

function loadAsyncScript(src) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    Object.assign(script, {
      type: 'text/javascript',
      async: true,
      src
    });
    script.addEventListener('load', () => resolve(script));
    document.head.appendChild(script);
  });
}
const initMapScript = () => {
  if (window.google) {
    return Promise.resolve();
  }
  const src = `${mapApiJs}?key=${apiKey}&libraries=places&v=weekly`;
  return loadAsyncScript(src);
};

export default function Home() {
  const [locations, setLocations] = useState({ locations: ['no results'] });
  const searchInput = useRef(null);

  const onChangeAddress = autocomplete => {

    const place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    const longitude = place.geometry.viewport.Ia.lo;
    const latitude = place.geometry.viewport.Wa.lo;
    restaurantReq(longitude, latitude);
    // console.log('longitude', longitude);
    // console.log('latitude', latitude);

  };

  const initAutoComplete = () => {
    if (!searchInput.current) return;

    const autocomplete = new window.google.maps.places.Autocomplete(searchInput.current);
    autocomplete.setFields(['address_component', 'geometry']);
    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', () => onChangeAddress(autocomplete));
  };

  const reverseGeoCode = ({ latitude: lat, longitude: lng }) => {
    restaurantReq(lng, lat);
    // console.log('location:', lat, lng);
  };

  const findMyLocation = () => {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
        reverseGeoCode(position.coords);
      });
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    initMapScript().then(() => { initAutoComplete(); });
  });

  const ContextMenuId = id => {
    const context = useContext(AppContext);
    context.route = parseRoute('home');
    context.updateMenuId(id);
    console.log('Id', id);
  };
  const restaurantReq = (lng, lat) => {

    fetch(`https://trackapi.nutritionix.com/v2/locations?ll=${lat},${lng}&distance=30mi&limit=20`, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'x-app-id': '',
        'x-app-key': ''
      }
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => setLocations(data)
      )
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
      .catch(err => console.log('Fetch Get error:', err));
    console.log(locations);
  };

  if (locations.locations.includes('no results') || locations.locations.length === 0) {
    const locArr = locations.locations.map((loc, index) => <h2 key={index}>{loc.name}</h2>);
    return (

      <div>
        <div className='text-center'> <h3>The purpose of this website is to help you lose weight by showing you
          meals that are under 500 calories at the closest fast food locations to you.</h3></div>
        <div className='row text-center'>
          <div className='col-full'>
            <form>
              <label htmlFor="address" className='block padding'>
                Enter Address to view nearby restaurant menus
              </label>
              <input type="text" placeholder='Address' required className='address-input'
                ref={searchInput} />
              <i className="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-location-dot" onClick={findMyLocation} />
            </form>
            <div>
              <div>{locArr}</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );

  } else if (locations.locations.length > 1) {
    const LocSetup = (location, index) => {

      const miles = location.distance_km / 0.621371;
      if (index % 2 === 0) {
        return <div className='col-half' key={index}>
          <h2><a href={location.website} target="_blank" rel="noreferrer" className='rest-link'>{location.name}</a></h2>
          <h3><button onClick={() => { ContextMenuId(location.brand_id); }}> Link to items on menu under 500 calories</button></h3>
          <h4>{location.address} {location.city} {location.zip} {location.state}</h4>
          <h4> {miles.toFixed(2) } miles away </h4>
        </div>
        ;
      } else {
        return <div className='col-half' key={index}>
          <h2><a href={location.website} target="_blank" rel="noreferrer" className='rest-link'>{location.name}</a></h2>
          <h3> Link to items on menu under 500 calories</h3>
          <h4>{location.address} {location.city} {location.zip} {location.state}</h4>
          <h4> {miles.toFixed(2)} miles away </h4>
        </div>;
      }
    };

    const locArr = locations.locations.map(LocSetup);

    return (

      <div>
        <div className='text-center'> <h3>The purpose of this website is to help you lose weight by showing you
          meals that are under 500 calories at the closest fast food locations to you.</h3></div>
        <div className='row text-center'>
          <div className='col-full'>
            <form>
              <label htmlFor="address" className='block padding'>
                Enter Address to view nearby restaurant menus
              </label>
              <input type="text" placeholder='Address' required className='address-input'
                ref={searchInput} />
              <i className="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-location-dot" onClick={findMyLocation} />
            </form>
            <div>
              <h1>Nearby Restaurants</h1>
              <div className='row'>{locArr}</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only call hooks on top level of the component.

```
export default function Home() {
  const [locations, setLocations] = useState({ locations: ['no results'] });
  const searchInput = useRef(null);
  // Use hooks only on top-level
  const context = useContext(AppContext);

  const ContextMenuId = id => {
      // const context = useContext(AppContext); <-- remove
      context.route = parseRoute('home');
      context.updateMenuId(id);
      console.log('Id', id);
    };
```

Comment: Thank you, was stuck on this the entire day yesterday, I'm new to using hooks